# Angular Service/Controller not returning promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angularjs-http

so I finally got my app working to where it gets the right URL for the JSON request. However now I can't get it work with that URL.

I understand that the service is returning the promise from the Google Maps API, which I probably shouldn't do but if I leave it out I get a "Weather.getWeather is undefined" error. I don't know why.

How can I get this to work correctly. Thanks for any help.

```
weatherService.getWeather = function(city)  {


        var coordsUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + city;


        return $http.get(coordsUrl)
            .success(function(data) {
                var coords = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat + ',' + data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

            return getWeatherData(coords);  

        }); 

function getWeatherData(coords)  {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
            apiKey = 'cbbdddc644184a1d20ffc4a0e439650d',
            weatherUrl = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/' + apiKey + '/' + coords + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';


            $http.jsonp(weatherUrl)
                .success(function(data) {

                    deferred.resolve(data);

                }).error(function(err) {

                    deferred.reject(err);

                });

            console.log(weatherUrl);

            return deferred.promise;
        }        

    };
```

Controller:

```
vm.fetchWeather = function(city) {

    Weather.getWeather(city)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            vm.place = data;
    });
};
```

Comment: `$http` methods return a promise, wrapping them in a `$q.defer()` is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use `.success` in your `getWeather` service function that wouldn't allow you return any sort of `data`. Because callback function's are not capable of returning anything [**Read Here about callback & promise**](http://www.randomthink.net/blog/2012/10/callbacks-and-promises/). So you should go for the promise recipe to dealing with asynchronous request, basically you can return data from the promise function to consumer function which calls that function. Actually it does call the consumer `.then` function, when ajax completed.

You need to simply use `.then` function in your `getWeather` function, then on resolve of that async call it will call the `getWeatherData` function which again will again returns a promise. So when it gets resolved it call .then function of `getWeatherData` when it returns data from it, at that time `Weather.getWeather(city)`'s `.then` function will get call. This whole thing is nothing but you implemented in promise chain. One function wait for other's, once the underlying promise gets resolved, it call its `.then` function.

[**Read here about Promise**](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/promises)

**Code**

```
return $http.get(coordsUrl)
 .then(function(resp) {
    var data = resp.data
    var coords = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat + ',' + data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    return getWeatherData(coords);  
});
```

Also there is not need of creating an extra promise inside `getWeatherData` function as you can utilize the promise of `$http` call there.

**Code**

```
function getWeatherData(coords)  {
    var apiKey = 'cbbdddc644184a1d20ffc4a0e439650d',
    weatherUrl = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/' + apiKey + '/' + coords + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

    return $http.jsonp(weatherUrl)
    .then(function(resp) {
       var data = resp.data;
       //you could play with data here before returning it.
       return data;
    },function(error) {
       return error;
    });
}
```

**Edit by Roamer-1888**

Alternatively, modify `getWeatherData()` to accept `data` and to calculate `coords` for itself. Then, the flow control statement will simplify to `return $http.get(coordsUrl).then(getWeatherData);`.

```
weatherService.getWeather = function(city) {
    var coordsUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + city;
    function getWeatherData(data) {
        var apiKey = 'cbbdddc644184a1d20ffc4a0e439650d',
            coords = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat + ',' + data.results[0].geometry.location.lng,
            weatherUrl = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/' + apiKey + '/' + coords + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
        return $http.jsonp(weatherUrl);
    }
    return $http.get(coordsUrl).then(getWeatherData);
};
```

Comment: Hey Pankaj, I'm still not fully getting it. Could you explain in a little more detail. Thanks!

Comment: @DevonAero sure..give me 5 minutes please

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Pankaj! However, now my controller is returning 'undefined' and not the data Object.

Comment: @DevonAero try updated.Actully i missed to use `.then` in `$http.jsonp(weatherUrl)` .I'm updating my answer with detailed..

Comment: Opps, nevermind. I missed the return statement in your example. But, figured it out myself haha. Thanks so much for you help. So I don't need to ever use the $q object or the success callback?

Comment: @DevonAero no..basically `$q` implementation is already there in `$http` call thats why I told you avoid that..you need to use `$q` whenever you wanted to do ajax which is not going from angular context..

Comment: @DevonAero look at the answer..now hoping its clear for understanding

Comment: It's finally starting to click! I'll do some more research, but I can't thank you enough for all your help!

Comment: @DevonAero never mind dude..Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: Change `getWeatherData()` to accept `data` and to calculate `coords` internally, then the flow control statement will simplify to `return $http.get(coordsUrl).then(getWeatherData);`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Great idea..go ahead and edit an answer..:)

Comment: @PankajParkar, OK done. I've left out the `var data = resp.data` bit but please add it if you think its important.